# Why does the coefficients of the expansion of (2x+1)^n produce the elements of the hypercube?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Why does the coefficients of the  expansion of $(2x+1)^n$ produce the elements of the hypercube?

For elements I mean the number of vertices, edges, square faces, cubes, hypercubes, etc that the next hypercube will have. For example for the tesseract:

$(2x+1)^4=16 x^4+32 x^3+24 x^2+8 x+1$

Meaning that the Tesseract has: 16 vertices, 32 edges, 24 square faces, 8 cubes and 1 tesseract as its elements.

Comment: Could you add some more detail, what do you mean by components of the hypercube?

Comment: We understand hypercubes, your term "components" was non-standard...

Answer (score 4):

The $k$-th coefficient of $(2x+1)^n$ is $2^k\binom nk$. The $n$-cube can be modeled as the graph with vertices the elements of $\{0,1\}^n$ connected iff they differ by one digit. Using this, can you count the number of $k$-cubes an $n$-cube contains? Note it has $2^n$ vertices (the $0$-cubes) and $n2^{n-1}$ edges (the $1$-cubes).

> *Spoiler* The formula is $2^{n-k}\binom nk$. We can create a $k$-cube inside an $n$-cube as follows. First, pick a vertex. This can be done in $2^n$ ways. Now, pick $k$-spots in that vertex. Then start changing them. This gives a $k$-cube. But this $k$-cube has $2^k$ vertices, and any of those would have worked in obtaining it. Thus, the final result amounts to $2^n\binom nk/2^k=2^{n-k}\binom nk$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to appeal to the binomial theorem; aim to see the result directly. The point is that we can think of an $n$-dimensional cube as the cartesian product $[0, 1]^n$ of $n$ copies of the $1$-dimensional cube, that we can break up $[0, 1]$ into two vertices $\{ 0 \}, \{ 1 \}$ and an open edge $(0, 1)$, and that cartesian product distributes over disjoint union. For example, when $n = 2$,

$$\left( \{ 0 \} + (0, 1) + \{ 1 \} \right)^2 = \{ 0 \} \times \{ 0 \} + \{ 0 \} \times (0, 1) + \{ 0 \} \times \{ 1 \} + (0, 1) \times \{ 0 \} + \dots$$

This is best explained by a picture but I can't find an existing picture that does what I want. In any case it's better to think of the result as an expansion of $(2 + e)^n$ where $e$ stands for the open edge so that the exponent of $e$ matches with the dimension of the corresponding face.

Answer (score 1):

The number of $m$-dimensional cubes on a $n$-dimensional cube is given by
$$
2^{n-m}\binom{n}{m}
$$
(see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube#Elements)).

Expanding your polynomial (via the [Binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)) gives the same numbers as above for the coefficients.